# Spotfire Filter applies to all visualizations of a dataset

Tags: spotfire

I have an input excel file of the below format on which I would like to develop a spotfire visualization on. I see that when I have different types of visualization - say a bar chart and a pie chart, the filters that I apply on one of the visualizations, say pie chart ( filter = hide the contribution of one type of Error Code ), I see that the same filter is also getting applied to bar chart as well. How do I prevent this from happening - my intention is to have the information depicted in bar chart as it is, and in the pie chart, I should be able to omit the success scenario ( as the pie char looks better if we remove success cases, which constitute 95% of the time ).[image]

```
12NC            Error Code      Rev     Message
4022.636.83462  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'ASML_Cable'. This is not allowed.
4022.640.89121  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'ASML_Cable'. This is not allowed.
4022.640.99082  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4022.642.46621  ERROR_BOM_19    AC  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4022.646.43312  ERROR_BOM_19    AB  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'ASML_Cable'. This is not allowed.
4022.656.01171  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4022.657.56421  ERROR_BOM_19    AB  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4035.201.14311  ERROR_BOM_19    AB  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4035.201.14541  ERROR_BOM_19    AB  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
4035.201.14551  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
ANCI.634.36431  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
ANCI.634.68222  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
ANCI.646.02261  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
TOOL.646.02261  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
TOOL.656.05741  ERROR_BOM_19    AA  Item contains precise BOM View of type 'view'. This is not allowed.
REQS.651.79400  SKIP_04             Item is already under SAP Change Control.
REQS.656.04000  SKIP_04             Item is already under SAP Change Control.
REQS.656.26040  SKIP_04             Item is already under SAP Change Control.
REQS.656.63550  SKIP_04             Item is already under SAP Change Control.
REQS.666.33330  SKIP_04             Item is already under SAP Change Control.
4022.431.39244  SUCCESS AD          OK
4022.435.60995  SUCCESS AA          OK
4022.435.62125  SUCCESS AB          OK
4022.436.18892  SUCCESS AA          OK
4022.436.50823  SUCCESS AB          OK
4022.436.50833  SUCCESS AB          OK
4022.436.66971  SUCCESS AB          OK
4022.436.79342  SUCCESS AC          OK
4022.436.79582  SUCCESS AB          OK
4022.437.25653  SUCCESS AE          OK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use a **Limit by** expression.

1. right click your visualization and click **Properties**
2. open the **Data** page of the Properties dialog
3. scroll down until you see **Limit data by expression** and click the **Edit...** button
4. enter a boolean expression like `[Message] != "OK"`

another way is to create a new **Filtering Scheme** and assign it to specific visualizations, but the process is not as straightforward and can lead to confusing user experience if abused.

Comment: Yes, I found the Limit Data by expression resolving my problem. Thanks a lot @niko.